# iPad: H.264 vs MPEG 4?

Tags: ipad, video

On the Apple website it is said that

> Camera Connection Kit support standard photo formats, including JPEG
>   and RAW, along with SD and HD video formats, including H.264 and
>   MPEG-4.

aren't H.264 and MPEG4 the same thing? I thought that there are two names only because different standard consortiums have different terminology.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With MPEG-4 you generally mean H.263, the predecessor of H.264. It has lower compression and therefore lower image quality at same bit rate.

Answer (score 1):

H.264 = MPEG-4 AVC = MPEG-4 Part 10